# how can i download with php curl on the remote page with cookies?

Tags: php, curl, download, remote-access

**UPDATED SCRIPT**

I am trying to login to a web page and save the session in a text file.

The login was success and redirect me to the members page or other page if i need.

but now i need download a file with curl, and the server says **Fatal error: Out of memory**

```
  ini_set("memory_limit","2048M");    //Limite 2GB
  set_time_limit(0);                  //Tiempo de transferencia ilimitada

  //Definimos las variables de la pagina
  $username    = ""; 
  $password    = "";
  $loginUrl    = 'http://login.mysite.com/login.php';
  $loginFields = array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password);

  //Ahora se ha iniciado la sesion y la sesion de la cookie ha sido generada
  getUrl($loginUrl, 'post', $loginFields); 

  //Cargamos la pagina que queremos ver
  $remote_page_content = getUrl('http://miembros.mysite.com/3098');
  echo $remote_page_content;

  //Simple funcion para acceder
  function getUrl($url, $method='', $vars='') 
  {
        $ch = curl_init();
        if ($method == 'post') 
        {
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $vars);
        }

        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7");
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        $buffer = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);

        return $buffer;
  }
```

so i call download file with this:

```
  //Cargamos la pagina que queremos ver
  $remote_page_content = getUrl('http://content.mysite.com/PSP.mp4/');
  file_put_contents('/downloads/video.mp4',file_get_contents($remote_page_content));
```

any idea?

thanks

Comment: What's in the cookie.txt after the first call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing your following lines:

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,  $cookies);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookies);
```

for this one:

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,  $cookie);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
```

as it seems you made a typo in the variable, you want the filename(`$cookie`) not the already closed descriptor (`$cookies`). This is inside your `login()` function.

**UPDATE**:
If you are working with multiple pages during ONE session, try adding this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, session_name() . '=' . session_id());
```

Comment: but in this mode the cookie isn't storage in the cookie file

Comment: why not? you tried? CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR and CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE expect a filename, that is what $cookie has.

Comment: Your problem may be due to fetching multiple pages from the same session, I've updated my answer with some options you could try.

Comment: i tried it. but not write anithing in the cookie.txt file, and the login i make correctly, but the download i cant do it with cookies

Comment: yes but i get an error **headers has been sent** but if i put `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION , true);` this do nothing

Comment: i get **Fatal error: Out of memory** message, why i got an error?